# Inbox message count animation too slow

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

The global inbox has an animated count which lets the red circle drop from above and fade in. This is nice and all, but it is quite too slow. If I am looking very quickly on the SO site, I sometimes think there is no message. And then, while closing the window, I suddenly see that there were messages.

Could we improve the speed of the animation or just make it appear `onLoad`?

Comment: I have never seen such animation.

Comment: Rip it out altogether...please.

Comment: I am having this in FF 5/6 at the moment.

Comment: I assume this UI was changed/removed long ago, so I'm closing this as no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This animation only appears for

1. very new users
2. users who haven't checked their global inbox in a very long time

It's intended to draw attention to the global inbox so new users can discover it and make use of it, since it's such an important part of the network.

[image: animated global inbox gif demo]

So if you want it to go away, a) earn ~15 rep and b) check your global inbox at least once every few days if you are on the site.

Comment: Is there any way to enable this animation? I'd try it for s while, until it got really annoying.

Comment: not really, other than a) or b) above

Comment: I see this animation every time I get a notification... Has there been some changes since this was posted?

Comment: @Lix, I think I only see it if a notification comes in when I already loaded the page. When refreshing, the icon is just there right away, *I think*.

Comment: @arj - I think you are correct... But I do still see the animation even though I check my inbox frequently and am not in the  "very new users" category (I think)...