# Animation of the global inbox

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, global-inbox

I was thinking whether it is possible to have some animation on Stack Overflow.

For instance, if a message comes then there should be a beep sound so that users can be alerted. I know that presently notifications are shown in red on the global inbox to mark its presence, but, if user is on some other tab or browser, then it is quite possible that he/she may not reply for quite a bit of time.

I thought by this way the comments can easily seek some attention quickly!

Comment: Just a title update, similar to how new questions are marked would be nice, indeed. I'd say no to sounds though. If you want to never miss a message, try the [Real-time desktop notifications for Stack Exchange inbox](http://stackapps.com/q/3780/9699?real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-extension) Chrome extension which I've written for this purpose.

Comment: Actually the little red notification bubble *does* have an animation when it appears. It kind of fades in with a slide down animation. So that is already covered. I don't think an audio prompt is needed as well though... If it was implemented, I sure hope there would be an option to mute it permanently..

Comment: That animation [is not shown to everyone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104046/inbox-message-count-animation-too-slow/104176#104176), @Lix. (But I very much agree with what you write.)

Comment: Hmmm, I see the animation all the time, and I'm not a new user. Maybe that post is outdated...

Comment: I see it every time too...

Comment: "beep sound" != animation...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I oppose this idea.

I really dislike websites that beep at me or randomly play anything with sound. I'm normally listening to something that *I* want to listen to; I don't want to be forced to listen to something that the website wants me to.

I also don't really see the point. If I'm online I normally flick back to the tab that has Stack Overflow occasionally to check if anyone has responded to a recent comment etc. If I don't want to pay any attention to comments then I don't look at the site. I don't think that this would change my habits at all.