# Is there a thread watcher option for stackexchange sites?

Tags: support

Like for [the site which shall not be named], where a sound notification option is available when a new post is made on the thread.

Comment: Requests for [audible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157365/animation-of-the-global-inbox/) notifications haven't gone down too well in the past...

Comment: @ben -10 is not that bad but yeah, don't think it encourage the team to implement such feature.

Comment: @Won't what's so horrible about that site that it's being censored like this, to the point of comments being deleted??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Quiet!  If you speak its name, it may hear, and come!

Comment: @Won't I didn't! Zalgo won't devour us all. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark a question as favorite - this will notify you of any new comments, edits and answers in your inbox.

There is no sound notification however.

Comment: Any firefox extensions or greasemonkey scripts?

Comment: @SreePrasannaRajagopal - Possibly. I am not aware of any.

Comment: Is this a new feature? I never got anything to my inbox, just a number next to "favorites" tab in my profile page saying amount of changes, then clicking the tab show what changed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Well, that's the notification I meant. It notifies you that _something_ changed, not _what_ has changed (no details).

Comment: Not quite what the OP here was after (he need to go to the profile page to see it, no sound or anything) but as he marked this as accepted guess it's good enough for him. :)

Comment: I actually found an extension that could do a popup. I edited Oded's answer to add it. I don't know why it was removed.

Comment: @SPRajagopal don't change existing answers, instead share it in a comment and the author (Oded in this case) might add it himself to the post. Another option which might be even better is to add your own answer with it and mark it accepted.